# Why when I try to run npx react-native run-android build failed and taking long time to execute these process

Tags: react-native

when I run `npx react-native run-android` it giving Error the following shows the content of error message
npx react-native run-android
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> w: /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactExtension.kt: (10, 37): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactExtension.kt: (119, 30): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactExtension.kt: (135, 26): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactExtension.kt: (157, 32): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactExtension.kt: (163, 31): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactExtension.kt: (171, 36): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactPlugin.kt: (114, 48): 'reactRoot: DirectoryProperty' is deprecated. reactRoot was confusing and has been replace with root to point to your root project and reactNativeDir to point to the folder of the react-native NPM package
> w: /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/TaskConfiguration.kt: (10, 37): 'ApplicationVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/TaskConfiguration.kt: (11, 37): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/TaskConfiguration.kt: (12, 37): 'LibraryVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/TaskConfiguration.kt: (27, 51): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/TaskConfiguration.kt: (130, 12): 'ApplicationVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/TaskConfiguration.kt: (131, 12): 'LibraryVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/TaskConfiguration.kt: (251, 14): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> Checking the license for package Android SDK Tools in /home/krishna/Android/Sdk/licenses
> License for package Android SDK Tools accepted.
> Preparing "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)".
> "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" ready.
> Installing Android SDK Tools in /home/krishna/Android/Sdk/tools
> "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" complete.
> "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" finished.
> Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in /home/krishna/Android/Sdk/licenses
> License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 accepted.
> Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)".
> "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" ready.
> Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in /home/krishna/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.3
> "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" complete.
> "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" finished.
> Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 31 in /home/krishna/Android/Sdk/licenses
> License for package Android SDK Platform 31 accepted.
> Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision: 1)".
> "Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision: 1)" ready.
> Installing Android SDK Platform 31 in /home/krishna/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-31
> "Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision: 1)" complete.
> "Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision: 1)" finished.

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
> Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libc++_shared.so, libevent-2.1.so, libevent_core-2.1.so, libevent_extra-2.1.so, libfabricjni.so, libfb.so, libfbjni.so, libflipper.so, libfolly_runtime.so, libglog.so, libglog_init.so, libhermes-executor-debug.so, libhermes.so, libimagepipeline.so, libjsi.so, libjsijniprofiler.so, libjsinspector.so, liblogger.so, libmapbufferjni.so, libnative-filters.so, libnative-imagetranscoder.so, libreact_codegen_rncore.so, libreact_config.so, libreact_debug.so, libreact_nativemodule_core.so, libreact_render_animations.so, libreact_render_attributedstring.so, libreact_render_componentregistry.so, libreact_render_core.so, libreact_render_debug.so, libreact_render_graphics.so, libreact_render_imagemanager.so, libreact_render_leakchecker.so, libreact_render_mapbuffer.so, libreact_render_mounting.so, libreact_render_runtimescheduler.so, libreact_render_scheduler.so, libreact_render_telemetry.so, libreact_render_templateprocessor.so, libreact_render_textlayoutmanager.so, libreact_render_uimanager.so, libreact_utils.so, libreactnativeblob.so, libreactnativejni.so, libreactperfloggerjni.so, librrc_image.so, librrc_root.so, librrc_scrollview.so, librrc_text.so, librrc_textinput.so, librrc_unimplementedview.so, librrc_view.so, libruntimeexecutor.so, libturbomodulejsijni.so, libyoga.so.

> Task :app:installDebug
> Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'M2101K6P - 12' for :app:debug

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
38 actionable tasks: 38 executed
Note: /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/android/app/src/debug/java/com/purenative/ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[CXX1101] NDK at /home/krishna/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529 did not have a source.properties file
Unable to install /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user
at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:327)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:307)
at utorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:342)

```
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:51)
at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor$ExecuteTasks.call(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:54)
at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor$ExecuteTasks.call(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.execute(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$executeTasks$7(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:161)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$tryTransition$7(StateTransitionController.java:174)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.tryTransition(StateTransitionController.java:174)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.executeTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:161)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkGraphController$DefaultBuildWorkGraph.runWork(DefaultBuildWorkGraphController.java:156)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.doRun(DefaultBuildController.java:164)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.access$000(DefaultBuildController.java:45)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController$BuildOpRunnable.run(DefaultBuildController.java:183)
at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base@11.0.16/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7m 16s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/android/app/src/debug/java/com/purenative/ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[CXX1101] NDK at /home/krishna/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529 did not have a source.properties file
Unable to install /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7m 16s

```
at makeError (/home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
at /home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (/home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/home/krishna/Documents/workspace/13oct2022/PureNative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:142:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Follow React-native and android setup from [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

**Node & Watchman**

brew install node
brew install watchman

**Java Development Kit**

brew tap homebrew/cask-versions

brew install --cask zulu11

**Android development environment**

1. Install Android Studio
2. Install the Android SDK
3. Configure the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable